# Improper date formatting, with time

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
today = str(now.year) + '-' + str(now.month) + '-' + str(now.day)
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(today, "%Y-%m-%d")
print(date) # 2020-11-13 00:00:00
```

Why is time added to date? I explicitly define my format without time.
How to have date only: 2020-11-13?

Comment: because it's `datetime.datetime` object, not `datetime.date`. And what's the purpose of all this? why not just `datetime.date.today()`? Note that you specify the input format, not the output. The output is `datetime.datetime` object

Comment: Indeed, please post this as an answer and i'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format string you specify in `datetime.datetime.strptime()` is the format of the string argument you pass to the method, not the output. The return value of the method is `datetime.datetime` object. Anyway, you can use `datetime.date.today()` to get `datetime.date`, i.e. without time.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `date` is a datetime object (not a date object), it has attributes hour, minute and second set to zero. if you `print` it, you effectively call its `__str__` method - which returns isoformat with space as separator. That's why you get `Y-m-d H:M:S`.

If you want today's date as string, simply use

```
from datetime import date
print(date.today())
# or
print(date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")) # same as date.today().isoformat()
# or even
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

# all print to 
# 2020-11-13
```